# multiprocessor programming and memory management

Tags: c, memory, non-volatile-memory, multicore

I'm working for a project (an embedded storage system) that requires to increase a memory access speed using a multiprocessors programming, so that we can execute a memory access program (storing data) in parallel with computing program. I'm a newbie in these topics **(multiprocessor programming, memory access tools)**. I got lost in the net and I could found just some books that talk superficially about this or just introduce it. I believe there are some resources that can offer a practical deep understanding. I need your help to find some practical resources about these topics, some code sources or... As a newbie in these topics, any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Your question is too broad. You won’t find people to do internet research for you on general topics. You need to ask specific questions, with your code included, and schematics where appropriate.

Comment: Do you run barebone, your very own kernel? If not, the kernel does all this for you already.

Comment: @BlairFonville thank you so much for your advice. i think if someones have dealt with these topics, they would suggest some resources that they walked through. that's why i needed help. for example me i got little familiarized with FPGA, so i can suggest some docs that can give newbie a clean deep idea in a shorter time and effort. you see the reason behind my question? Thanks again!

Comment: @Janka the project is a development cost trend, so i think we need to find a solution in shorter time but which responds to the spec. i think we will use multicore board (e.g. raspberry). A time ago, I could make a cross-compiler for beaglebone board (embedded linux things), do you think that i can adopt the kernel for my needs on the raspberry? thanks in advance!

Comment: The question stays the same: Do you want to use an existing kernel, e.g. Linux, or create your own?

Comment: @Janka honestly i don't have a great idea about how much time it would take to build a kernel (few months or one year or more). But if you think "building my own kernel" would be an efficient approach to manage the memory access according to my needs, my answer would be "yes, i want to build a kernel". for a sake of development time, don't you think that it's possible to just adopt the existing kernel in the board? (sorry if my question is stupid)

Comment: @Janka As i'm looking to increase the memory storage speed, do you think that i can build a new kernel so that i can manage a memory access specifically for my specifications? thanks for your help!

Comment: If you don't have a clue, stick to Linux (or another kernel) and, at most, tune some parameters as I/O scheduling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a course in college which we program multiprocessors.Here are some sources, which we use:

- M.J. Quinn: Parallel programming in C with MPI and OpenMPI, Mc Graw Hill, Boston, 2003 Internet
- N. Matloff: Programming on Parallel Machines, University of California, Davis
- http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/158/PLN/ParProcBook.pdf

I hope this will somehow help. My course was not in English language so main books are not translated.

Comment: i will look for them right now and then reply. thanks in advance!!

Comment: if you think that the main books would help too, i would try my best to translate and understand them. thanks a lot!